# Simple Image Gallery Pro submitform is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0

I am running Simple Image Gallery Pro 3.0.4 on a Joomla 3.3 website. The gallery creates images correctly, but I am unable to save captions or descriptions. When I view the gallery in SIG Pro, add my captions, and click "Save", nothing happens.

When I checked the console in Firebug, I get this error:

> ReferenceError: submitform is not defined submitform(pressbutton);

Comment: It looks like you've found a solution - what's the question here?

Comment: Yes it is a solution and i would like to share it, if it is possible of course

Comment: Then answer your own question instead of putting it in the comments. On the other hand, this is a VERY isolated issue that isn't likely to help anyone.

Comment: Building on @patricksweeney 's comment, there is a checkbox when you create a question to "Answer your own question".  That would be the preferred way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: I can't answer my own question now, I have to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 4):

I searched and i found a solution to correct this problem

To correct this problem

In the file /administrator/components/com_sigpro/script.js at the line 55, replace

```
 submitform(pressbutton);
```

with

```
if ( typeof submitform === 'undefined') {
    $sig('#adminForm').find('input[name=task]').val(pressbutton);
    $sig('#adminForm').submit();
}else{
    submitform(pressbutton);
}
```

I hope it can help someone

Comment: It does help indeed, although I think the problem (at least for me) lies in the fact that core.js (where `Joomla` object is defined) is not being loaded in the admin page.

Answer (score 1):

Add the function below on the script file:

```
function submitform(task) {
   $sig('input[name=task]').val(task);
   $sig('#adminForm').submit();
}
```